Different use cases for watering patterns for different types of vegetables
I would like to ask, why is it that during gardening, often, water must be placed on the side of the plant, often in a slight sulk, rather than from above, is it because the leaves may rot, and, in each case, why would they rot, and, why is it bad to pour too much water?
What are the specific use cases of watering patterns for different kinds of vegetables?
Thanks.

Roots need water, directly and to get nutrients. So watering "side" or just drop irrigation will put water where it is needed, and much less evaporation. I do it on zucchini (and similar because powdery mildew is strong in my region). I do it also with salads (lettuces, etc.): large leaves, else water will stay in the middle not going down to soil.
Else I do not care much (and you see on open field the same: drop irrigation is expensive). Tomatoes: I tend to water longer, but few times (so more days without watering): roots will develop better. So in this case you must pour a lot of water in terrain. On other vegetables I may visually check, and often I water every few days (or once a week at beginning season, if weather is not too hot).
Garlic, potatoes, onion, etc. do not water when leaves are turning yellowish: for long term storage I want dry soil when I harvest them.
"Too much water": saturating soil may be good (and I do), but it should not be done too often. Soil should dry up, not to rot roots and let them to work properly.
In any case, in my experience: soil is tolerating much more watering errors, comparing pots. I have no real experience on raised bed, they may be in the middle ground.
